# Let $q_n$ be the smallest prime that is strictly great than $P_n = p_1 p_2 \dots p_n + 1$, prove $q_n - p_1 p_2 \dots p_n$ is always prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $q_n$ be the smallest prime that is strictly great than $P_n = p_1 p_2 \dots p_n + 1$, prove $q_n - p_1 p_2 \dots p_n$ is always a prime.

It's from Elementary number theory 7th by David M. Burton and is a conjecture. What is the name of this conjecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is called [Fortune's conjecture](https://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/F/Fortunes_conjecture.html), with the smallest integer $m \gt 1$ where $p_n\# + m$ (where $p_n\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)) is a prime number, being called [Fortunate numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number).

Note that, in addition, there are also currently at least $6$ related questions on this site, e.g., as shown in this [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Fortune%27s+conjecture).